# Changing WAMP's www directory

Tags: google-drive-api, wampserver

I'm trying to transfer WAMP's www folder into Google drive folder, so I have access to files everywhere, I have changed two lines in httpd.conf: DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/" and  to drive folder, but WAMP icon stays orange and fails to open localhost. Any help, or better way to connect these two? Thanks.

Comment: So what have you changed them to?

Comment: I changed them to point the Google drive folder.

Comment: Will you install WAMPServer on every PC you want to develop on?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is a permissions issue. Right click 'Google Drive' Folder -> Properties -> Security Tab -> Advanced -> Click 'Include inheritable permissions from parent folder'. Done!

Original from https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/4LWRozCv14E